# FTP with caching support

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am very happy with Filezilla FTP, but one thing that it lacks is the caching support of folders. I see that feature is in SmartFTP, but it's not free..

Are there any FTP software that supports folder caching?

Comment: I found blazeftp, but it's not that nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) is a free, open source utility that has the ability to communicate in many different transfer protocols, one of them being FTP. [It also has an FTP directory caching feature](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/directory_cache).

[image]

Note that the directory reading options will not be visible unless advanced options are enabled.

Comment: I didn't link the software, but as promised I am giving my +50 bounty because of your help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the FileZilla FTP Client version 3 does do directory caching, but has no option to turn it off.

If you go back to FileZilla version 2.2.32, this is still optional :

[image]

Comment: Too bad there is no option to control the caching. I guess, the caching is temporary and will get cleared once I exit the software.

Comment: Yes, that will happen with any ftp client, not only FileZilla.